# Extract middle name

Tags: vb.net, substring

I need to find out how to extract the middle name from a full name to be displayed in an output text box, so far I can only get the middle name and half the last name to be displayed. The main issue I am having is I dont know how to get the indexOf the second space which seperates the middle and last name. Code so far:

```
Private Sub btnClick_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
    Dim fullname, firstname, middlename, lastname As String
    Dim n, m As Integer

    fullname = txtFullName.Text
    n = fullname.IndexOf(" ")
    m = fullname.LastIndexOf(" ")
    firstname = fullname.Substring(0, n)
    lastname = fullname.Substring(m + 1)
    middlename = fullname.Substring(n, m)
    txtMiddleName.Text = middlename

End Su
```

Comment: the sure fire way is to provide 3 textboxes and collect 3 names so you dont have to parse `Admiral Richard Lord Howe` incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

Once you've found the first space, split the string into two strings, one with everything before the first space and one with everything after it. Then you can split that second string at its first space to extract the middle name.

I should point out, however, that this is all nonsense because it makes bogus assumptions about how humans are named. There are first names with spaces in them. "Mary Lou" and "John Henry" can both be first names.

There really is a person named "Yuv Raj Vig". What do you think his first name is? It's not "Yuv". It could be "Raj", because "Yuv" can be a title, but it's not that either.

Comment: You make an excellent point about the meaning of "middle name"; it reminds me of this article I read several years ago. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/   It's something that every new programmer should read.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Falsehood 30 is particularly relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `String.Split()` function to break the string on the space character (tell it to ignore sequential separators in case there are extra spaces between names).  This will get you an array of each "word" in the name.  If the array has a length of exactly 3 then you can get the middle name by looking at the 2nd element.  If the length is anything other than 3 then there is no way to know for sure which is the middle name.

```
    Dim name As String = "James Tiberius Kirk"
    Dim names() As String = name.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If names.Length = 3 Then
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("The middle name is {0}.", names(1)))
    End If
```

You could probably get even fancier by splitting using a RegEx, but then you would have 2 problems.